# getJSON breaks on page refresh (F5). How to fix?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an ajax call that fires every five seconds to update some data on the screen. It seems that the getJSON breaks after a page refresh. What appears to be happening is that if the page refreshes via F5 while the call is happening, the future calls won't work. They simply fail with no error message. The textStatus is error but errorthrown is empty. I'm calling into an Asp.Net MVC controller and no error is fired there. The subsequent getJSON calls never hit the server. It's pretty much hosed at this point until I start and stop my website again. No idea how to fix this as I can't stop the user from refreshing the page and it's a pain for me to test updates.

Here is my code:

```
var RealTimeActivity = (function () {
    var realTimeActivity = {};
    var timer = null;
    var active = false;

    realTimeActivity.LastUpdated = new Date();

    function queueUpdate() {
        timer = setTimeout("RealTimeActivity.Update();", 5000);
    }

    function reset() {
        clearTimer();
        queueUpdate();
    }

    function clearTimer() {
        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = null;
        }
    }

    realTimeActivity.Update = function () {
        try {
            clearTimer();
            if (active === true) {
                $.getJSON("realTimeActivity/GetRealTimeData",
                    function (result) {
                        if (result.Success) {
                           // do stuff
                        } else {
                           // Other stuff
                        }

                        queueUpdate();
                    }
                ).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
                    reset();
                })
            }
        } catch (ex) {
            reset();
        }
    }

    realTimeActivity.Start = function (i) {
        active = true;
        if (i) {
            realTimeActivity.Update();
        } else {
            queueUpdate();
        }
    }

    realTimeActivity.Stop = function () {
        active = false;
        clearTimer();
    }

    return realTimeActivity;
}());
```

**EDIT:**
This appears to only be reproducible in Chrome. A bug in chrome perhaps or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you check the status of `var active` after refresh?

Comment: Can you run fiddler and check what is the response that you get?

Comment: @PabloWeb18 - RealTimeActivity is always null on refresh before I reassign it to my function. Therefore active is inaccessible. It's set to true when the timer is started up again and doesn't seem to be causing any issues.

Comment: @Narayana - Fiddler doesn't show the request at all once the getJSON starts failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a caching issue with Chrome and aborted requests. It will not allow me to send another request to the same URL once the request is aborted even after refreshing the page. I worked around it by making every request unique (via a timestamp).

```
  postRequest('realTimeActivity/GetRealTimeData?u=' + (new Date).getTime(), null, function (response) {
```

Apparently you can also call $.ajax and just set cache to false as well which does the same thing behind the scenes.